# Reset a lwc table to his initial values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

i have made a search bar, when i click "show results" a table with all the results appears, but I would like to make also a "reset" button that if clicked make all the table of results empty again
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method to empty the data array.

```
employeeData.splice(0,employeeData.length);
```